# Regex replace all matches but not the first and last character

Tags: java, regex

I'm afraid I looked over something obvious. But I want to match and replace words. But only if there is a non-letter character is both preceding on tailing. Like match `kaas`:

```
<p>Kaas bla bla
bla more kaas, bla 
another line adding more kaas to....
```

This regex works \P{L}kaas\P{L} (kaas is a variable). But when I replace `kaas` with `cheese`, I get:

```
<pcheesebla bla
bla morecheese bla 
another line adding morecheeseto....
```

Now I can do:

```
final String nonChar = "\\P{L}";
final String dutchWord = "kaas";
final String englishWord = "cheese";
final String text = getText();
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(nonChar + dutchWord + nonChar);
final Matcher match = p.matcher(text);
while (match.find()) {
    final int start = match.start();
    final int end = match.end();
    final String c1 = Character.toString(text.charAt(start));
    final String c2 = Character.toString(text.charAt(end - 1));
    final String result = match.replaceFirst(c1 + englishWord + c2);
    //final String result = match.replaceAll(c1 + englishWord + c2);// not a `c1` and `c2` are equal
}
```

Which, works only once, because I can't get the right information out of `Matcher` to figure out the preceding and tailing character of `kaas`. I'm pretty sure I saw something on looking forward and backward regex characters - I think. I tried using `?:` but I keep getting `PatternSyntaxException`s.

What do I need to add to fix this? And how in Java. Does it make a difference that I'm using `P{L}` instead of `*w` type of characters for this?

Note: the reason I use `P` is this should also work for non-Western languages, which I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookarounds for zero-width assertion here:

```
(?<!\p{L})kaas(?!\p{L})
```

This will only assert that `kaas` is not preceded or followed by another unicode letter.

In java it will be:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\p{L})" + Pattern.quote(dutchWord) + "(?!\\p{L})", 
                   Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

PS: It is safer to use `Pattern.quote` for a user provided input.

Comment: Great start! I'm just not sure which characters will not be handled with the p{L}... Apparently not `<`, but what about Chinese, Korean, stuff like that?

Comment: `\p{L}` will match any unicode letter in any language.

Comment: I can live with that :p... Thanks!

Comment: I tried... But I had to wait for 1 minute (SO told me ;-) )

Comment: Btw, it doesn't seem to support uppercasing

Comment: I told you in my last comment (4 days ago), it doesn't support uppercasing... which is an easy update to your question, just add a parameter. It took me some time to figure that it was incomplete, hence not an answer. But I didn't want to create an own answer, solely because of the ignoreuppercase tag

Comment: Actually I didn't understand what you meant by uppercasing. If you want to  do **ignore case match** then use `final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?<!\\p{L})" + Pattern.quote(dutchWord) + "(?!\\p{L})");` Besides there was no mention of `uppercasing` requirement in your answer.

Comment: `<p>Kaas` first code sentence, `, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`, I've added it, so that the answer corresponds to the question

Comment: Thanks for your edit, yes `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` has same behavior as `(?i)` in front of regex.

Comment: I didn't want to take away your credits... Just the attention to upgrade... nonetheless, thanks for helping me out!